# Regular expressions: ignore what is quoted in a string

Tags: java, regex

If I have the string `"This is > than" something 1=3 and "else = true"` (dont try to understand what it means, its just an example:P ) how can i replace a custom pattern that is not contained by quotes? For example replace the '='(equals) operator, the first one, with lets say '<' resulting in the string  `"This is > than" something 1<3 and "else = true"`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: While regex can be used here I have a feeling that writing your own parser would be much simpler and probably more effective.

Comment: Would you like to have an escaped quote as part of a quoted and/or unquoted section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to replace all the `=` which was present outside the `"` with `<` symbol.

```
=(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Replacement string:

```
<
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/11)

```
System.out.println("\"This is > than\" something 1=3 and \"else = true\"".replaceAll("=(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", "<"));
```

Output:

```
"This is > than" something 1<3 and "else = true"
```

Comment: is there any way I can give a list of elements to match? for example if it finds one of the following (>, =, <, <=, >=,!=)

Comment: yes, give it inside non-capturing group, and seperate the chars with `|`, that is `(?:>|=|<....)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this search pattern:

```
=(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

And replace it by:

```
<
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sN6lG7/1)

**In Javacode:**

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("=(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)", "<");
//=> "This is > than" something 1<3 and "else = true"
```

Answer (score 0):

While other answers seems simple they are based on idea of testing if founded `=` is outside quotation by making sure that each `"` after it has its closing `"`, which means that this regex need to iterate over rest of the string from `=` you are testing. This can be very ineffective if your string is long and you have many `=` in it to test.

Alternative way to solve this problem could be finding either quoted areas or searched substrings. Then if we wind quoted area we don't change it, but when we find `=` we can apply different logic (we can change it to something else like in your case `<`). This solution has this advantage that while finding for quoted area we can consume all non-quote characters, so we will also consume `=` which we don't want to change, which means that if we will match `=` we are sure that it wasn't inside `"..."` so we can avoid time consuming test from other answers.

Possible code for such solution can look like

```
String text = "\"This is > than\" something 1=3 and \"else = true\"";

// This regex will search for areas which starts with ", ends with " and have zero
// or more non quotation marks between them. If such area will be found it will be 
// placed in group named "quotation". Searching for such group have higher priority so 
// I put this variant before `=` variant (or other variants)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<quotation>\"[^\"]*\")|>=|=|<|>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group("quotation") != null) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group("quotation"));
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "<");
    }
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Output: `"This is > than" something 1<3 and "else = true"`